# lm-sensors: "watch sensors" shows fewer sensors than just "sensors"

Tags: lm-sensors

I have a weird situation with lm-sensors: when launched with 'sensors', it shows all the sensors, including fans, but when I launch it to update automatically, with 'watch sensors', it doesn't show them all, the fans are missing. Is there some configuration issue going on?

Answer (score 0):

... I'm an idiot. The moment I pressed enter I had a revelation: maybe if I enlarge the window...? And it worked. 'watch sensors' only shows the sensors that fit in the window, it doesn't let you scroll down to show more, you have to make the window taller. I'll leave this answer here in case someone else is a bit thick like me :)